# How to digitally sign PDF files with smartcards in .NET?

Tags: .net, security, pdf, digital-signature

I have a smartcard that stores my digital certificate. When I plug it into my PC, the certificate shows up at the Windows certificate store, under IE > Tools > Internet Options > Content > Certificates.

So... How can I use such certificate to sign a PDF file in .NET?

Answer (score 2):

Check http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html. Maybe you need to change the key store to the ["Windows-MY"](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/security/) keystore.

Answer (score 0):

See our [PDFBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pdf.php) components that let you sign PDF files using certificates on smartcards and USB tokens. As far as I know, PDFBlackbox is the only PDF signing component to support private keys stored on hardware (and thus not exportable to the system).